# How do I mount a digital camera via the command line?

Tags: command-line, mount, camera

When I plug in in my digital camera (Fuji F100fd), Nautilus automounts it as 'USB PTP Camera' with the path 'gphoto2://[usb:001,007]/'.

`lsusb` lists it as `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04cd:02ef Fuji Photo Film Co., Ltd`

`dmesg` says `usb 1-3: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 7`

How can I mount it from the command line (not running GNOME/X)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean from the commandline while you are not in GNOME?

You can use gphotofs for that.

```
sudo apt-get install gphotofs
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Maybe it's worth mentioning its limitations: "GPhotoFS currently can't add or remove directories, rename files or directories, add or modify files and get space information."