# Error when trying to get movies off my Camera

Tags: 10.10, shotwell, camera, dbus

How do I retrieve movies and audio files from my Canon PowerShot S5 IS camera?

Shotwell only sees the pictures. Mounting the camera via *"Places > Canon Digital Camera"* and then clicking twice on the resulting desktop icon yields this error:

```
could not display "gphoto2://[usb:001,002]/"
```

There is nothing in `/media`.

[image: gphoto2 error message]

**update:** output of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 40.0 GB, 40007761920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4864 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3ee33ee2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2364        2612     1999872   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2   *           1        2364    18979840   83  Linux
/dev/sda3            2613        4864    18089159+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5            2613        4864    18089158+   b  W95 FAT32

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

**Solution:** install *gphotofs*, then Nautilus shows camera contents similar to a standard usb storage device (though note that gphotofs does not yet support adding to or deleting contents).

Comment: How do you connect your camera?Through USB cable?

Comment: yes, through usb.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` with your your usb device(that is your camera) plugged in.

Comment: @karthick, added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you could try accessing the files via the command line. In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10455/how-do-i-mount-a-digital-camera-via-the-command-line), 
`gphotofs` was suggested for mounting the camera.

Comment: gphotofs solved it, but not in the manner indicated! After installing gphotofs selecting the camera from the *Places* menu opens a Nautilus window showing the contents of the camera as standard usb storage device.

Answer (score 4):

Shotwell 0.8 will support video, including importing them off cameras: http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/855

We're considering adding audio support in a future release: http://trac.yorba.org/ticket/2920